# BootStrap 3.0 grid system not containing text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am just learning the new bootstrap grid system however it is very different from 2.x and I can't seem to get it to contain anything, it just flows on out.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJMMU.png

[image]

Code: http://pastie.org/8272634

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>ICG - Home</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/over.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" id="blue" href="#">iCanGame</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Community</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">All Games</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="navend"></div>
    <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-10">left</div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="wrap">sdsafdsafdsafdsafdsafdsajlsdhakfhdksahlfdsahkfldsakfhkdsakfdkjslahfdskhaflhdksaklfhdsaklfdkhsa</div></div>
              </div>
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the text has been overflowing because your sample text is a single word you have not included any space between those...
Please find code below..

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-10"><p>left</p></div>
                <div class="col-xs-2"><div class="wrap"><p>
sdsafds dhakfhdks ahlfdsahkf ldsakfhk   dsakfdkj slahfd skhafl   hdksaklfhds aklfdkhsa</p>   </div></div>


</div>
```

Comment: I had no idea that mattered.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two **.col-md-12**, shouldn't you be using only two **.col-md-6** classes, since the **.col-md-12** are *width:100%* divs?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are giving a no-space-contain word.

Ex: 
string like *adfjklsdjfaksdjfsakldjfsakl;fjsakl;djf* **won't work.**

instead, string like *asdfkljsd;lf   asdfkjds   asdkfjklj*  **will work**

And the grid system will not cut single word into two line.

By the way, give testing paragraph by typing will not be a great idea.

Try Something like [paragraph generator](http://watchout4snakes.com/wo4snakes/Random/RandomParagraph)
to generate random paragraph.